# registerClick Method crashes my android app

Tags: java, android, samsung-gear-fit

When I try to trigger the `registerClick` method, the app crashes.

I committed my code to this branch https://github.com/jackygrahamez/MayDay/tree/gear-fit

**HomeActivity.java**

```
    Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
    boolean startedByCUP=false;
    if(bundle!=null) {
        startedByCUP = bundle.getBoolean("START_BY_CUP");
        Log.e(">>>>>>", "START_BY_CUP");
        //multiClickEvent.registerClick(System.currentTimeMillis());
        multiClickEvent.registerClick(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
```

**MultiClickEvent.java**
    package com.mayday.md.trigger;

```
import android.util.Log;

public class MultiClickEvent {
public static final int TIME_INTERVAL = 10000;
private static final int TOTAL_CLICKS = 5;

private Long firstEventTime;
private int clickCount = 0;

public void reset() {
    firstEventTime = null;
    clickCount = 0;
}

public void registerClick(Long eventTime) {
    if (isFirstClick() || notWithinLimit(eventTime)) {
        firstEventTime = eventTime;
        clickCount = 1;
        return;
    }
    clickCount++;
    Log.e(">>>>>>", "MultiClickEvent clickCount = " + clickCount);
}

private boolean notWithinLimit(long current) {
    return (current - firstEventTime) > TIME_INTERVAL;
}

private boolean isFirstClick() {
    return firstEventTime == null;
}

public boolean isActivated() {
    return clickCount >= TOTAL_CLICKS;
}
}



02-07 21:21:52.249  13534-13534/com.mayday.md I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 13534 SIG: 9
02-07 21:21:55.669  13710-13710/com.mayday.md I/PersonaManager﹕ getPersonaService() name persona_policy
02-07 21:21:55.699  13710-13710/com.mayday.md I/PersonaManager﹕ getPersonaService() name persona_policy
02-07 21:21:55.739  13710-13710/com.mayday.md D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:720 height:1280 bitmap id is 270
02-07 21:21:55.749  13710-13710/com.mayday.md I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 28.465MB for 8294416-byte allocation
02-07 21:21:55.769  13710-13710/com.mayday.md D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:28 height:10 bitmap id is 271
02-07 21:21:55.779  13710-13710/com.mayday.md D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:10 height:28 bitmap id is 272
02-07 21:21:55.779  13710-13710/com.mayday.md D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:12 height:12 bitmap id is 273
02-07 21:21:55.789  13710-13710/com.mayday.md D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:96 height:96 bitmap id is 274
02-07 21:21:55.789  13710-13710/com.mayday.md D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:96 height:96 bitmap id is 275
02-07 21:21:55.789  13710-13710/com.mayday.md D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:96 height:96 bitmap id is 276
02-07 21:21:55.799  13710-13710/com.mayday.md D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:96 height:96 bitmap id is 277
02-07 21:21:55.799  13710-13710/com.mayday.md D/AbsListView﹕ Get MotionRecognitionManager
02-07 21:21:55.809  13710-13710/com.mayday.md D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:1 height:1 bitmap id is 278
02-07 21:21:55.809  13710-13710/com.mayday.md E/>>>>>>﹕ START_BY_CUP
02-07 21:21:55.809  13710-13710/com.mayday.md D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
02-07 21:21:55.809  13710-13710/com.mayday.md W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41742da0)
02-07 21:21:55.809  13710-13710/com.mayday.md E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mayday.md, PID: 13710
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mayday.md/com.mayday.md.HomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2453)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:173)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5579)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.mayday.md.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:63)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2453)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:173)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5579)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: `multiClickEvent` does not point to a valid instance using the code you provided. Ergo, it is `null`

Comment: I defined the `private MultiClickEvent multiClickEvent;` at the start of the HomeActivity.

Comment: I am aware. However, that doesn't *instantiate* it, it just declares a `null` reference that can point to a `MultiClickEvent`. In Java, non-primitives must be instantiated using the `new` keyword.

Comment: This also fails
      MultiClickEvent multiClickEvent = null;
         if(bundle!=null) {
            startedByCUP = bundle.getBoolean("START_BY_CUP");
            Log.e(">>>>>>", "START_BY_CUP");
            multiClickEvent.registerClick(System.currentTimeMillis());
        }

Comment: I see now I had to use `new` it does not yet achieve my goal of registering the click though